# How to add click eventListener to Material Design Tabs <md-tab> in an Angular 4 app written in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material2

I'm building an Angular 4 app with TypeScript and trying to add click event listeners to Material Design Tabs `<md-tab>` with no success.

I've tried different approaches but none of them seems to work.

Here is a simple HTML tabs example:

```
<md-tab-group>
    <md-tab label="Tab One">
        <p>Some content here</p>
    </md-tab>
    <md-tab label="Tab Two">
        <p>Some other content here</p>
    </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

**1. First Approach:**

Material Design seems to generate the tab elements in the DOM dynamically, and giving the elements unique ids, so I've tried to target these ids in the TypeScript file `constructor()` function:

```
let tab1 = document.getElementById('md-tab-label-0-0');
let tab2 = document.getElementById('md-tab-label-0-1');
```

and add an `eventListener()` function to both properties:

```
tab1.addEventListener("click", () => {
    this.currentTab = 'my-first-tab';
});
tab2.addEventListener("click", () => {
    this.currentTab = 'my-second-tab';
});
```

but the problem is that `tab1` and `tab2` properties are returning `null` so this isn't working:

**2. Second Approach:**

I've tried to add a `(click)` binding to the HTML `<md-tab>` element:

```
<md-tab-group>
    <md-tab label="Tab One" (click)="checkActiveTab('my-first-tab')">
        <p>Some content here</p>
    </md-tab>
    <md-tab label="Tab Two" (click)="checkActiveTab('my-second-tab')">
        <p>Some other content here</p>
    </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

in the TypeScript file I've initialized the returned value with the `currentTab` property, but the `checkActiveTab()` function is not triggering, so this isn't working either:

```
checkActiveTab(elem: string) {
    this.currentTab = elem;
}
```

Can anyone give me an idea of how can I do this? Basically, I would like to set the `currentTab` property based on the active tab.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to get what tab is selected? If so, you can just use `selectChange` *Output* of `md-tab-group`... `<md-tab-group (selectChange)="changeSelection($event)">`... and in component do whatever do you want with `$event`.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! I was over complicating because didn't know about (selectChange) method. Thanks man!

Comment: I just remembered I answered this question before :)